# FSM in Graphviz: Many transitions from node to itself

Tags: graphviz

I've drawn a rather complex state machine in graphviz with mutliple connections from a node to itself. As you can see, the result isn't readable at all, is there a way around this? Thanks

(can't upload here, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybL76.png)

Comment: If you could upload the code, it might be possible to advise. However, in the meantime, you could try changing `rankdir`, which can help when there are long labels as there appear to be here.

Comment: there is no grapviz solution for that. maybe you could rework your state machine to get a less complex design.